# La fausse liaison dans "quatres enfants" ?

Tags: phonétique, liaisons

J'ai lu dans un livre que "quatres enfants" est un exemple de la fausse liaison, mais je ne comprends pas pourquoi. Je pensais que la liaison était obligatoire dans cet exemple. Pourriez-vous m'expliquer pourquoi elle n'est pas obligatoire ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'article parle d'une fausse liaison car elle n'existe pas en français formel, *quatre* étant invariable.

A l'oral, *quatre* perd souvent son *r* final (apocope) et se trouve donc réalisé en /kat/.

> - Il a quatre fils : /ilakatfis/
> - [L'Opéra de quat'sous](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Op%C3%A9ra_de_quat%27sous)

Quand l'adjectif *quat'* est suivi par une voyelle, le *r* réapparaît le plus souvent mais si ce n'est pas le cas, la marque du pluriel (un *s* qualifié parfois d'euphonique mais l'Académie parle de [plaisanterie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/quatre)) se fait parfois entendre, d'où les

> - [quat'z'amis](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Quat%27z%27amis)
> - bal des [quat'z'arts](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quat%E2%80%99z%E2%80%99arts)
> - [entre quat'z'yeux](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/entre_quat%E2%80%99z%E2%80%99yeux)

et ici:

> - les quat-z-enfants

Comment: +1 Si je me rappelle bien j'ai lu quelque part que ce type de "liaison" est tolerée mais pas conseillée par l'académie française. Je ne trouve pas  la source malheureusement. Je crois que c'est un livre du Certificat Voltaire.

Comment: @dimitris Tolérée par l'Académie seulement dans *entre quat'z'yeux* qui est la seule façon dont est prononcée cette expression.

Answer (score 1):

L'adjectif numéral « quatre » est un mot invariable, il ne s'écrit pas avec un s et ne peut jamais en avoir; de même le substantif « quatre » est invariable. Donc cette orthographe qui est utilisée (quatres enfants) est inexacte et on ne peut pas discuter la liaison; il doit s'agir d'un autre exemple. De plus , il semble qu'il s'agisse non pas de « fausse liaison » mais de « liaison interdite ».

Soit dit en passant que pour ce groupe nominal, lorsque il est correctement écrit (quatre enfants), la liaison se fait normalement.