# What is the right way to pronounce "4" and "21" in French?

Tags: nombres, dialectes

I was watching this video and she says that **quatre** pronounce as "cat".

Also **vingt** pronounce as "va" and **vingt et un** pronounce without **et**.

But this webbpage says that **quatre** pronounce as **qatre** and that's more fair in my opinion. Also **vingt** pronounce as **vint** and **vingt et un** pronounce as **vint e a**. Which is more close to just **vint a**

Also listen to **quatre** in the web page. It's not pronounced as **cat**.

So which one is right? 
Is there a dialect between them two?

[French numbers 1-100 (Learn French With Alexa)](https://www.thefrenchexperiment.com/learn-french/numbers)

[French numbers](https://www.thefrenchexperiment.com/learn-french/numbers)

Comment: You are hitting one of my pet gripes! Welcome, by the way :-) It seems to be mostly English speakers who sin against French (and just about any other language). The worst one, which makes me shiver every time, is when I hear 'Ypres' pronounced as 'Eep'.

Comment: Note that both your links point to the same page

Comment: The problem with us English folk is we heard the "un-deux-trois cats sank" rhyme in our youth ...

Comment: @WillCrawford I heard that French people don't prononce some letters in a word. Why? Was it to hard?

Comment: Eliding the odd syllable here and there is just as common in English as it is in French, and I've already come across a few common Japanese phrases that drop a mora or two. I think sometimes it's not so much difficulty, as that things you say often and are more than a handful of words seem to want to be abridged... :) For example, "je suis" often becomes something like "schwee" and similar contractions happen to "je ne suis pas" ("schwee pa") and "je ne sais pas" ("chez pa").

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*Quatre* is often pronounced a little like the English "cat" or "cut" (but with a slightly different vowel) unless it is followed by a word starting with a vowel in which case the /r/ is almost always pronounced (e.g. *Elle a qua**tr**e ans*). The final r might not be pronounced in *quatre euros* (*c'est quat'euros*) and in a very few cases, an extra /z/ appears in spoken French (quatre-z-yeux, quatre-z-amis, ...). See [La fausse liaison dans "quatres enfants" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32607/la-fausse-liaison-dans-quatres-enfants/32609#32609)

When *quatre* is ending a sentence, it is also often pronounced [/kat/](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quat%E2%80%99) (e.g. *J'en ai vu qua**t** <sup>re</sup>.*)

*Vingt* before a pause can be pronounced with or without the final *t*. There is no single "standard pronunciation", the standard mostly depending on the region. The *g* is on the other hand never pronounced. The pronunciation of the nasal vowel ***in*** widely vary depending on the region or the people, and might indeed be close to the vowel /a/. The *et* of *vingt-et-un* is always pronounced so *vingt-et-un* is never pronounced like would be the hypothetical *vingt-un* (or *vingt ans*) and even less like we pronounce *quatre-vingt-un* (where no /t/ is heard).

See also: [Pronunciation of "vingt"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/pronunciation-of-vingt/7569#7569)

and

[Mathieu Avanzi, le français de nos régions](https://francaisdenosregions.com/tag/vingt/) :

[image]

Comment: "cat"? You mean "cut", don't you? I learnt "cut-r" or "cut-r(ö)". Disclaimer: Neither English nor French is my native language.

Comment: @rexkogitans It might be either. The way the vowel is pronounced in the French *quat'* or the English *cat* and *cut* substantially vary depending on the locutor. The usual phonological representation of *quat'* is /kat/ while "cat" is either /kat/ or /kæt/ and "cut" is /kʌt/. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I once spoke with an alsacien and we were arguing over the pronounciation of *vingt*, as I pronounce it *vin* and him *vinT*, so I asked him to say 80 and he pronounced it *quatre-vin* (without the final T). Funny, right?

Comment: @Rafalon Well, that's the standard pronunciation in eastern France. Do you pronounce the *T* in *cent euros* ?

Comment: @jlliagre No, I don't. Do they?

Comment: @Rafalon Slightly more French native people do not pronounce the *T* of *cent* in *cent euros* but definitely pronounce it in *cent ans*. Many "pronounce" that 'T' like a *Z* in *cent hommes*... Go figure ;-)

Answer (score 11):

In everyday speech, these are generally fine.

- *vingt* can sound as if it has `/ɑ̃/` like "an" rather than `/ɛ̃/` like "in" depending on how far back the speaker pronounces that vowel. Compare the first two recordings [here](https://forvo.com/word/vingt/). And [here](https://forvo.com/word/cent_vingt_et_un/#fr), one speaker actually uses the same vowel for "cent" and "vingt", whereas the other doesn't.

  - To my knowledge, most speakers delete `/t/`, but some do not. However, in "vingt-et-un", the liaison from "et" means you *will* hear the `/t/` on the end of "vingt". Listen [here](https://forvo.com/word/j%27ai_vingt_et_un_ans/#fr).
- *et* can be virtually elided in fast speech — not totally but enough to make it hard to hear
- *quatre* will tend to lose the `/r/`, much like every word ending in "-re" or "-le" (*table* `/tab/`) when speaking informally

We'd need to see the video to know for sure, but from the description that pronunciation is okay.

Comment: I would note that while 21 is "vingt et un", 81 is "quatre-vingt un" without the "et". This may be part of the confusion surrounding the "et".

Comment: @MatthieuM. Good observation.

Comment: @MatthieuM. No, the two contexts have nothing to do with one another. Just as you keep apart without problem such constructions as « entre chien et loup » and « un chien-loup » so do you not mix « vingt-et-un » and  « quatre vingt un».

Comment: @LPH but people who are still learning the language may nonetheless be confused from time to time about which number properly includes the word *et.*

Comment: I'm not convinced by your liaison explanation. The t is also pronounced in vingt-deux, vingt-trois, ... where there is no such liaison.

Comment: @phoog Yes, I agree with that, nothing is more true.

Comment: @Edouard Not sure how you distinguish that from the next consonant. What about 24, 25?

Comment: Thanks to this discussion I have just discovered that I sometimes pronounce the "g", as in "vingt-quatre": vin-g-t-c-atre. But I have never heard anyone cut off the "et" in "vingt-et-un".  Go figure.

Comment: @PatrickT *Vingue-teu-quatre*, really!! 

Comment: @jlliagre, yes, I couldn't believe it myself.

Comment: @jlliagre French here, I would say *Vin-teu-quatre* or faster *vinte-quatre*, the *g* is never pronounced (*vin-té-un*, *vinte-deux*, *vinte-trois*, *vinte-quatre*, *vinte-cinq* and so on until *vinte-neuf*)

Comment: @Rafalon Well, the *G* is never pronounced **except** by PatrickT, at least according to his statement. Je demande à voir...

Comment: vin-thé-un, surely?

Comment: @jlliagre Yes, I think I over-read his comment, but I can tell I've never heard anyone pronouncing it

Comment: @jlliagre Concernant 24, et en lisant PatrickT parler de sa prononciation du *g*, je me suis rappelé mon enfance, pendant laquelle ce nombre recevait un traitement particulier de ma part. Je remplissais la transition entre la nasale *(in)* et la plosive *(k)* d'un *(gn)*, obtenant qqch comme [vɛ̃ɲ.kat] ou [vɛ̃ŋ.kat]. Si cette prononciation fait partie de mon passé, je traite, encore aujourd'hui, 22 & 23 de façon similaire, mais les *d* ou *t* initiaux de 2 & 3 étant alvéolaires plutôt que vélaires, je remplis plutôt d'un *n*: [vɛ̃n.dø], [vɛ̃n.tʁwɑ].

Comment: @jlliagre Je note aussi que pour ces trois nombres, je réalise [vɛ̃], alors que pour les autres nombres de cette dizaine, je réalise [vẽ], selon la réalisation québécoise habituelle du phonème /ɛ̃/: bien→[bjẽ], gain→[ɡẽ], ceinture→[sẽt͜sʏʁ], brimbale→[bʁẽbal], etc.

Comment: @ﺪﺪﺪ Intéressant. Quand j'étais petit, je prononçais  *véingtéung'* [vɛiŋteỹŋ], *véinnteudeu*  [vɛiŋtødø], *véinnteutrois* [vɛiŋtøtʁwɑ], *véinnteuquatreu*  [vɛiŋtøkatʁø] ...

Comment: @jlliagre Quel charmant accent! J'adore ce [vɛiŋteỹŋ]! Par ailleurs, on sent la méridionalité dans le [katʁø]: ce n'est vraisemblablement pas au Québec que des enfants développeraient cette prononciation.

Answer (score 2):

> La langue populaire, à peu près partout, réduit au premier élément les
>   groupes consonantiques finaux dont le deuxième élément est *r* ou *l*
>   : *quatre* prononcé °[kᴀt] ; *souffle* prononcé °[suf].
>  <sub>À
>   l'intérieur d'un syntagme, cela appartient simplement au registre
>   familier : *Votre papa* [vɔt pᴀpᴀ]. Dans le nom composé
>   *quatre-quatre* (§ 597, d, 1°[« véhicule automobile dont les quatre roues sont motrices. »]), la prononciation [kᴀt] pour le premier
>   élément est à peu près générale.</sub>
>  <sub><sub>Devant voyelle,
>   le groupe reste intact : *Quatre amies*.
>  Autres réductions
>   populaires : *-isme, -iste* prononcés °[is] dans *communisme,
>   communiste*, par ex. ; — *ex-* prononcé °[ɛs] devant consonne : dans
>   *exclure*, par ex.</sub></sub>
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §36
>   « suites consonantiques » c) ]

Comment: Il y a 20 ans on constatait déjà : « [...] tout le monde relâche sa prononciation de façon naturelle, réductions de formes discursives ou non : les jeunes ne sont pas des « massacreurs de la langue » pas plus que les personnes âgées ne sont les « invalides de la langue ». Au-delà de problèmes de génération, le stéréotype de la dévaluation de la jeunesse semble très prégnant : il permet de légitimer le discours de ceux pour qui évolution et dégradation sont confondues. » (Wachs Sandrine. _Le relâchement de la prononciation en français parlé en Ile de France_. (résumé), Lang. et soc., 1998).

Comment: Re: your comment: Just because young people tended to speak a certain way twenty years ago, that doesn't *necessarily* mean that they continued to speak that way as they grew older. Age-related speech differences can be stable for a surprisingly long time. (Example #1: in anglophone Canada, the letter 'Z' in anglophone Canada is called /ziː/ by children and /zɛd/ by adults. This has been the case for several decades at least. Example #2: in Alsace, people have claimed for generations that alsacien is on the verge of death because kids no longer learn it.)

Answer (score -1):

**I** "Quatre" will be pronounced "cat" especially in rapid speech. At the end of a sentence it is never pronounced "cat" (substandard).

- Combien de chaises se trouvent dans cette pièce ? Il y en a quatre.
- Combien en voyez-vous ? J'en vois quatre. Je vais les prendre tous les quatre.

For instance, it is impossible to say "quatre cents fois" rapidly, you have to say "cat cents fois". However, when speaking slowly you do have a choice and it is not wrong to say "quatre cents fois" in full.

**II** "Vingt-et-un" should always be pronounced  /vɛ̃.t‿e œ̃/. The type of pronouciation that you can hear on this page, https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vingt-et-un#Prononciation, is not recommanded; you can still make out /e/ but it is blurred and almost melted into the following  /œ̃/; that is not typical of people who speak well.

**III** "Vingt" is pronounced "vint" in some régions of France, but that is not standard French; the standard pronunciation is "vin" [vε ̃] ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vingt)); here are three very good pronunciations of "vingt": https://fr.forvo.com/word/vingt/.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103246/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-what-is-the-right-way-to-pronounce-4-and-21-in-f).

Comment: "At the end of a sentence it is **never** pronounced "cat" (substandard).". This is inaccurate.